# Variable value change in render()

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, semantic-ui-react

So here is a little bit of code to start with, I'll explain what I'm trying to achieve and what's not working next :

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className='custom-modal'>
        <Link to='/c' onClick={this.hideFader}>
          <Icon name='close' className='close-button' size='big' />
        </Link>

        <h1>Your contributions</h1>
        {this.props.requests.map(d => {
          return (
            <div className='chat-thread' key={uuidv1()}>
              <Link to={`/c/contribution/${d.id}`}>
                <div>
                  <h2>{d.title}</h2>
                  <p>{d.description}</p>
                  <p>ID: {d.id}</p>
                </div>
              </Link>
              <div>
                <Icon
                  name='close'
                  className='request-delete'
                  onClick={this.show}
                  size='big'
                />
                <Confirm
                  open={this.state.open}
                  content={`Are you sure you want to delete this request? All the information including the chat linked to this request will be deleted!`}
                  onCancel={this.handleCancel}
                  onConfirm={this.handleConfirm(d.id)}
                  size={'mini'}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

So this is my whole `render()` method.

What I try to do here is a little component that will redirect to a route, I achieved this with a `<Link />` and the route changing works (it redirects to the same id).

Now if you continue to read the code you'll see this `<p>ID: {d.id}</p>`.
This works well too (So what I mean with this is that the id I got in the `<Link />` and the id in `<p></p>` are the same.

Now here comes the tricky part, here is the specific part I'm talking about :

```
<Icon
   name='close'
   className='request-delete'
   onClick={this.show}
   size='big'
/>
<Confirm
   open={this.state.open}
   content={`Are you sure you want to delete this request? All the information including the chat linked to this request will be deleted!`}
   onCancel={this.handleCancel}
   onConfirm={this.handleConfirm(d.id)}
   size={'mini'}
/>
```

This part is in the same return, but for some reasons this line returns another id : 
`onConfirm={this.handleConfirm(d.id)}`

I tested this, and the first 2 id's return 1, the last one (the one above) returns 2 (2 is the id of the other element that is loaded in, there are 2 in total with id 1 and 2 respectively).

Here is my `handleConfirm(id)` :

```
handleConfirm = id => () => {
    console.log(id)
    this.setState({ open: false })
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/requests/${id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-User-Email': localStorage.getItem('email'),
        'X-User-Token': localStorage.getItem('token')
      }
    })
  }
```

So the console.log is putting out 2 while the other `d.id` are giving 1

EDIT: I did some checks, and what is happening is that no matter which delete button you click, it will take the id of the last one. So if there are id's from 1 to 5, no matter what you click, it will pass in 5.
If I do this out of the `<Confirm />` and add an `onClick()` on the `<Icon />` above it will work.
It seems like this is an issue with the `semantic-ui-react` package but not sure, can anyone point this out?

Comment: Your `this.handleConfirm(d.id)` must be getting called twice,  both times you are getting id as 2?

Comment: I get id 1 the first 2 `d.id` and I get 2 on the last one, the one you give me. Even if it is called twice I don't see why it would change, handleConfirm() is just passing that in a fetch.